# For C-Scan scheduling, requested queue location is same as head-start

Tags: operating-system, system, scheduling, disk

for C-Scan Disk Scheduling, if the head-start is at 100 and there exist a request that is also at 100(in a 10 request queue), do I automatically put it as the first in queue and move on with my normal C-Scan routine?